# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon

Tags: cassandra, installation

I want to try Cassandra. When trying to run Cassandra, writes an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon

What's the problem?

```
Java -version
Java version "1.7.0_67"
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get that error when you've downloaded a source distribution of Cassandra but haven't built it or when the CassandraDaemon.class file isn't in your classpath.

For the first problem:
You'll need the JDK 1.7 (which you already have) and ant to build C*. 
Navigate to wherever you've extracted cassandra (I'll use ~/cassandra for this explanation) , Run ant and enjoy the awesome.

For the second, if your classpath is setup incorrectly something has gone wrong in the build process or the classpath has been modified. I'd verify that the classpath is what is expected by displaying it in the startup script (the **cassandra** executable) by adding `echo $CLASSPATH` near the bottom of the script (in my case it was line 212 for C* 2.1.0).

P.S. On windows you'll need to set CASSANDRA_HOME before being able to run C*.

Comment: I do not have root access

Comment: echo $СLASSPATH 
prints nothing

Comment: @АлексейСидорин That pretty much means that none of your classes are being loaded. Here's an [example classpath](https://gist.github.com/lyubent/a95f0e03fdf566f32231).

Comment: Tell me what to do, I do not understand why this is so.

Comment: @АлексейСидорин I'd start digging through the cassandra script (the `bin/cassandra` file) that actually starts the server and find out why the class path isn't being built up.

Comment: I can not find the problem.
I am desperate.

Comment: @АлексейСидорин It's an odd issue and not having root privileges doesn't help at all. My advice at this point is re-download a compiled version of cassandra (a binary distribution) and try running that.